# How to transfer a file from local storage to two S3 buckets (Bucket A and Bucket B) in same time in php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a code to transfer file into a S3 bucket but now I have to transfer file into two S3 bucket (Bucket A and Bucket B) simultaneously through php . Their a simple way to do the same is - rewrite the code of transferring file for second bucket but I don't want to do this. Is there any another way to do it smartly. 
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean *in same time* ?

To send a file to one aws s3 bucket you need to initiate a request, within a single request you can only push a file to a single bucket, so you need to run 2 requests to push the same file to the 2 buckets.

To achieve seamless "simultaneously" and using the php v3 sdk you can run request in parallel as running each request in [async mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-transfer.html#async-transfers)

> The Transfer object is an instance of GuzzleHttp\Promise\PromisorInterface, which means that the transfer can occur asynchronously and is initiated by calling the promise method of the object.

```
$clientA = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
]);
$clientB = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
]);
$source = '/path/to/source/files';
$destA = 's3://bucketA';
$destB = 's3://bucketB';
$managerA = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($clientA, $source, $destA);
$managerB = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($clientB, $source, $destB);

// Initiate the transfer and get a promise.
$promiseA = $managerA->promise();
$promiseB = $managerB->promise();

// Do something when the transfer is complete using the then() method.
$promiseA->then(function () {
    echo 'sending to bucket A!';
});

$promiseB->then(function () {
    echo 'sending to bucket B!';
});
```

Comment: Thanks frederic for your response and Yes, you get it correct, same time means simultaneously. I already have this way of sending a file to two destination buckets. Is there any other way to doing this and one more thing I want to ask you - regions of both the destination bucket is different with this case , can I achieve the same ?

Comment: you will need to declare 2 clients, one for each region, see updated example. as for doing it differently, no all the other way will involve trigger after a first file is uploaded to trigger an event to replicate the file on the other bucket so you achieve duplication but not _simultaneously_ this is I think the best way to achieve seamless realtime

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Lambda function that copies the file to another bucket. An example implementation is given in [Content Replication Using AWS Lambda and Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/content-replication-using-aws-lambda-and-amazon-s3/). By using a Lambda function you would not have to modify the PHP application.

Comment: Thank you jbird, I have gone through the link you shared, But I don't want to send all the file to second destination bucket, I do want to send some specific files to both destination buckets and rest files in only single destination bucket and one more thing I want to ask you - regions of both the destination bucket is different with this case , can I achieve the same ?